# Should input data be scaled for real-time classification?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, lstm, real-time, tensorflow-lite

I'm developing an application which takes in the smartphone's sensor data (Accelerometer and Gyroscope) using the LSTM model. I have trained and tested the model and gained acceptable accuracy of around 95%.

I've scaled the training and the testing data (fitted the scaler on training data only) using StandardScaler() but my question is, if I were to deploy this model onto Android Studio to utilize the model for real-time classification, will it be a problem since I've trained the model using Scaled data but in the real world the data would be untouched data. Is there a method to apply the scaling data to the new data? If so, I would appreciate suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Your pipeline also should include a scaler in this situation. Whenever a new input comes your model should scale it then work on params.

Comment: I see, so the raw data should be scaled before it is fed through the model, therefore do you have any recommendations on the techniques that allows us to scale the raw data before feeding it into the model in real time? All the tutorials I have seen online only explain the scaling process during pre-processing and not at the deployment stage

Comment: Are you familiar with Tensorflow's functional API or custom models. You can easily do it with these.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with those, can you name a few of the functional API or custom models I should use so I can get started learning about them?

Comment: These are concepts that allow us to use TensorFlow layers flexibly. You need to learn by googling it. Or you can try to add a scaler like tft.scale_by_min_max into your Sequential model (Which I've never tried before)

Comment: Okay I'll look into it and thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to scale the data just like you are doing while training the data.

If you are having preprocessing pipeline before sending it to the model while training, you need to follow the same when you receive the live data and then call the model weight file.